# MVC5: Custom Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Instead of using `forms authentication` or `windows authentication` I need to call a custom authentication service. This service will return a JSON object that contains information about the user if authentication succeeds.

How would I integrate this in ASP.NET MVC 5?

For example: Is there a way where I can simply override the authentication step in the ASP.NET security pipeline and still use the authorization parts. How would I go doing that?

Comment: Have you looked at ASP.net Identity?

Comment: Adding single-sign-on is relatively easy with MVC5, if you look at the Startup.cs of a sample project, you can find demo commented out code to add facebook, twitter and google authentication, maybe that is a good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new MVC application with no authentication. Then I created a custom module that hooks into the ASP.NET request pipeline (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

```
public class MyAuthModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Implement when you need to release unmanaged resources
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthenticateRequest += Context_AuthenticateRequest;
        context.PostAuthenticateRequest += Context_PostAuthenticateRequest;
    }

    private void Context_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Call custom library to authenticate
        // and create a new ClaimsPrincipal with the info from the JSON object.
    }

    private void Context_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Optional: Inspect the ClaimsPrincipal and add more claims
    }
}
```

Then register this module in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="MyAuthModule"
         type="MvcDemo.Auth.MyAuthModule, MvcDemo" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```